# Creating lines between points within distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, distance, polyline-creation

I have a point layer and I'm Looking for a tool which connects every point of the layer with each other. Ideally, I can give a distance and the number of Connections for each point.

The following example is from the ArcGIS tool
[image]

In the example each point connects to nine other points which are within distance X Meters.

Is there a tool like that in QGIS or a Plugin or can it be done with the Geometry Generator somehow?

Comment: What ArcGIS took did you use to do that and was it from ArcGIS Pro or from ArcMap?

Comment: Also pay attention to these related threads: [1] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141078/generating-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis [2] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/creating-all-possible-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the distance, you could create a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) that connects nearby points.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query.

Note that the line is created once between 2 points (A-B is the same as B-A).

```sql
SELECT
    make_line(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry,
    a.id as fromID,
    b.id as toID
FROM
    myPointLayer a
JOIN
    myPointLayer b
    ON ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) < 5000
    AND a.id < b.id
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this the geometry field is null on a shapefile and a geopackage; should this still work for QGIS3?

Comment: @MrKingsley yes, it is still working. Make sure your layer is `point`, not `multipoint`