# Connecting all points to each other in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, points-to-line

I have a points layer of about 300 points, and I'm trying to find a way to draw lines between every pair of points (so 44,850 lines in total).

I've thoroughly perused similar questions here and tried all of them no avail.
I know R and Python, but have never used packages related to QGIS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating all possible line segments between all points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/creating-all-possible-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis). Here you even do not need scripting

Comment: Have a read of https://datacarpentry.org/r-raster-vector-geospatial/06-vector-open-shapefile-in-r/ which should help with opening your layers: one for the points and an empty shape for the lines then with a list of XY coordinates iterate and create new lines... however index the list with a range object for startPoint in ListRange: for endPoint in ListRange: if startPoint != endPoint to avoid a 0 length line; this will end up with duplicates in the opposite direction (A to B and B to A also), this may be what you want or it may not, please edit your question to indicate if duplicates are okay