# Geometry Generator Error. Too few points in geometry component

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I've created a line layer using my point layer through the geometry generator tool described in this [Creating all possible line segments between all points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/creating-all-possible-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis)
Then I've used Edit Geometry => Split features tool for lines (I had multilines and I split it through this tool on the short lines with only two points).
And now I get an error - invalid geometry. I've checked the geometry and the error is "Too few points in geometry component". I don't know why it's happened. Could somebody help me with it? I think that may be Null-length lines as a result of geometry generation step, but I don't know how to prevent it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try [Multipart to Singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts), then split the singleparts manually if you want to