# Linking points within a specified tolerance

Tags: point, vector, fme-form

I have a set of points, and I want to build lines between pairs of points whenever their separating distance is within a specified tolerance. For example, 3 or 4 meters. Is there a way to do it in FME?

Comment: I suggest you specify a software you're working with.

Comment: A short answer: yes it is possible, but to answer *how* we need more details and more focus from you. For instance, the decision about a software/tool, what have you tried etc.

Comment: Do they share some attribute? Or is it obvious which two pair of points should be connected?

Comment: I am working with ArcGIS, but I can manage to use Qgis or FME
Unfortunatly the points have no common attributes, just their X and Y coordinates

Comment: "I can manage to use three different softwares" is no specification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGIS: create lines to connect points which are within a distance to each other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/qgis-create-lines-to-connect-points-which-are-within-a-distance-to-each-other)

Comment: Hi Liana, i tried to write you a script but the thread is closed. So i loaded it into github, check it out. 
https://github.com/florjanv/Points-2-lines

Answer (score 1):

The **[NeighborFinder](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/neighborfinder.htm)** transformer is the tool for this.

> Finds the nearest Candidate feature(s) to each Base feature and merges
> their attributes onto the Base feature. May also be used in Candidates
> Only mode, where each feature is considered the Base in turn and
> compared to all other features, but not itself.

You can set the maximum distance to your tolerance of 3 or 4 metres.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script in arcpy:

1 - Create a empty geodatabase

2 - copy your points inside it

Points - should be in projected coordinates system (the length need to be calculated).

3 - Create an empty line feature inside this .gdb (in the same coordinate system with points)

4 - change the parameters, depending in your paths and change the tolerance

5 - run the script

6 - the result will be extended in the line feature class, and some useful information will be added (linked points id,coordinates).

https://github.com/florjanv/Points-2-lines

```
import arcpy
import math

#parameters
f = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\points\temp.gdb\Points" #input points feature class
lines_f = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\points\temp.gdb\Lines" #empty line feature class
tolerance = 4 #the tolerance in meters

#variables
feature_id = []
total_x = []
total_y=[]
lines = []

def main():
    desc = arcpy.Describe(f)
    noZvalue()
    #add joined fields
    try:
        arcpy.AddField_management(lines_f,"from_id","LONG")
        arcpy.AddField_management(lines_f,"from_xy","TEXT",250)
        arcpy.AddField_management(lines_f,"to_id","LONG")
        arcpy.AddField_management(lines_f,"to_xy","TEXT",250)
        arcpy.AddField_management(lines_f,"length","DOUBLE")
        arcpy.AddField_management(lines_f,"dub","TEXT",50)
    except:
        print("fields exists")


    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(lines_f,["SHAPE@","from_id","from_xy","to_id","to_xy"]) as cursor:
        for i in feature_id:
            if lines[i]:
                for j in lines[i]:
                    array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(total_x[i], total_y[i]), arcpy.Point(total_x[j], total_y[j])])
                    cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polyline(array),i+1,str(total_x[i])+", "+str(total_y[i]),j+1,str(total_x[j])+", "+str(total_y[j])])

    #remove dublicated lines
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lines_f,"length","!SHAPE_Length!","PYTHON_9.3")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(lines_f,"dub",'str(!length!) +", " +str(abs( !from_id! - !to_id! ))',"PYTHON_9.3")
    arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(lines_f, "dub")

        
 
def noZvalue(): #function for calculating the distances without Z coordinate
    oid = 0
    for a in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(f,["SHAPE@X","SHAPE@Y"]):
        total_x.append(round(a[0],4))
        total_y.append(round(a[1],4))
        feature_id.append(oid)
        oid+=1
    #fill the variable with id's that are nearer than 4m
    for i in feature_id:
        v1=[]
        for j in feature_id:
            dist=0
            dist = math.sqrt(math.pow(total_x[j]-total_x[i],2)+math.pow(total_y[j]-total_y[i],2))
            if dist<=tolerance:
                if dist ==0: continue
                v1.append(feature_id[j])
        lines.append(v1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result, calculated for 1000 points:

[image]