# Draw lines between points from two layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polyline-creation, points-to-line, geometry-conversion

In QGIS 3.10.4 on Mac, I have two multipoint shapefiles: one is *"Start"* points, and the other is *"To"* points. Each layer has `"x"` and `"y"` coordinate columns in the attribute table. "Start" points only have `"location_name"` (string) as IDs, and "To" points have ID numbers as IDs.

I also merged the two layers, so I have a layer that has both sets of points if needed.

My goal is to draw lines between each *"start"* point and each *"to"* point. Many plugins in other answers cannot be found now.

I'm wondering how can I do so?

The points look like the picture below, red dots are Start points, and blue ones are Tos.

[image]

Comment: I always suggest Python when it comes to such specific problems. You probably won't find an out of the box solution for this. If you provide me with some more data I can give you a hint on how to write it with PyQGIS. How are we supposed to know which points connect with which?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating line segments between all points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141078/generating-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis). Additionally you can check this thread [Creating all possible line segments between all points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/creating-all-possible-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis). Also do not forget about MMQGIS and Shape Tools Plugins.

Comment: Thank you @LeonPowałka. I'm trying to connect each red dot to each blue dot - there should be a line between each red dot to each blue one. Red dots have "location_name" (string) as IDs in the attribute table, blue dots have ID numbers as IDs in the attribute table.

Comment: Thank you, @Taras! Your answer to the first thread is exactly what I'm looking for. It worked perfectly. To whom may also want to use @Taras' script, if your layer is MultiPart, change it to SingleParts might be helpful.

Comment: @gislearner, please see the https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141078/generating-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis, i have extended it